# Included jQuery does not work on included html

Tags: jquery, html, include

In my project I want to use include for generic HTML parts. But when I include an HTML file the jQuery does not work anymore. Below is an example of my code looks like. In this situation I want to include the intro text in this page. The alert would work but the span with the class intro-text would also be visible while the code in main.js should make it hide. Anyone any ideas?

HTML-page

```
<div id="include-introText"></div>

<script src="main.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

  $('#include-introText').load('intro-text.html', function () {
     // nothing
  });

</script>
```

intro-text.html

```
<span class="intro-text">Hello, this is an intro text</span>
```

main.js

```
$('span.intro-text').hide();
alert('test')
```

Comment: That *HTML-component* confused me, is it a line in your *HTML-page*?

Comment: It's not really clear from the example what the issue is, however I would say that JS is far from the ideal method to use to create common includes. Do it server side instead.

Comment: Because your element `$('span.test')` doesn't exist

Comment: I've editted the example to make it more clear

Comment: I've tested your code, it works very well https://jsfiddle.net/xrenaz32/2/

Comment: Possibly the included HTML with the `intro-text` span hasn't loaded when the `hide` gets executed. Place the `hide()` in the success function of the `load`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because "main.js" is loaded before "intro-text.html", this means that main.js when is looking for

```
$('span.intro-text')
```

This returns nothing, this means that you are not hiding anything, then when intro-text.html is loaded it just show you that span. For prevent this, you must load main.js after intro-text.html is loaded.

```
<div id="include-introText"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

  $('#include-introText').load('intro-text.html', function () {
     var script = document.createElement('script');
     script.onload = function () {
        //do stuff with the script
     };
     script.src = "main.js";

    document.head.appendChild(script);
  });

</script>
```

Comment: Ah, yea I thought already that was the reason but I could not find a to fix it. This works, thanks!